# ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is visible on Linked Servers Provider, still can't import EXCEL file

Tags: sql-server

I just don't know what to do anymore. I've been searching in a LOT of topics. I"ve downloaded tons of providers from microsoft.

I'm trying to import an Excel file to a database. I've been having this problem since ever. some servers it works, some don't. Now I have one that it doesnt and for my surprise is my test environment.

When `task . Import data > DATA SOURCE: Microsoft excel` I receive this error:

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> The operation could not be completed.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine. (System.Data)
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

ok no problem let's install ACE OLEDB 12.

Got `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64` and installed.

I can see it's working because Is on providers:

[image: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh]

but then BAM! the same error.

Comment: God dammit if anyone is suffering, just open "import wizard" from the windows's start bar

Comment: Yes.  Using those drivers in a Linked Server is tricky, dangerous, and unsupported.  The Import/Export wizard loads the driver in short-lived SSIS proxy project running under the interactive user's identity, which is all Office drivers were designed to do.

Comment: is excel file on database server? AccessDatabaseEngine should be installed where excel file is. also try installing both 32 and 64 bit versions.